# ClickHouse 20.4.2.9 HeartbeatRequest failed: Broker: Unknown member: actions Permanent

Tags: clickhouse, apache-kafka

Clickhouse запущен в докер-контейнере и в логах контейнера постоянно сыпятся сообщения типа:

```
%7|1597869112.888|RECV|ClickHouse 20.4.2.9#consumer-6| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator/0: Received HeartbeatResponse (v3, 6 bytes, CorrId 379, rtt 2.19ms)
%7|1597869112.888|REQERR|ClickHouse 20.4.2.9#consumer-6| [thrd:main]: GroupCoordinator/0: HeartbeatRequest failed: Broker: Unknown member: actions Permanent
%7|1597869112.888|HEARTBEAT|ClickHouse 20.4.2.9#consumer-6| [thrd:main]: Group "chgroup" heartbeat error response in state up (join state wait-revoke-rebalance_cb, 1 partition(s) assigned): Broker: Unknown member
%7|1597869112.889|HEARTBEAT|ClickHouse 20.4.2.9#consumer-6| [thrd:main]: Heartbeat failed: UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID: resetting member-id
%7|1597869112.889|REBALANCE|ClickHouse 20.4.2.9#consumer-6| [thrd:main]: Group "chgroup" is rebalancing in state up (join-state wait-revoke-rebalance_cb) with assignment: resetting member-id
```

Естественно, в базу данных ничего не попадает. Clickhouse выступает consumer-ом для kafka и читает оттуда сообщения. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: пожалуйста, покажите логи CH, это должно прояснить детали - /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log. Было бы хорошо увидеть вашу конфигурацию KafkaEngine.

Comment: посмотрите на https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-kafka-engine-faq

Comment: @vladimir "посмотрите на altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-kafka-engine-faq" - кажется ссылка помогла. Я тормознул consumer и сбросил offset. Сейчас наблюдаю за работой, пока данные попадают в CH. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Отключение consumer и сброс offset помог.